# Signed variant of size_t in standard C++ library

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed, std, size-t

Is there a signed variant of size_t in standard C++? Meaning exactly same bit size as size_t but signed.

Of course I can do:

```
#include <type_traits>
using signed_size_t = std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>;
```

but maybe there is already similar definition in standard library, not to invent extra type name?

I know there are ssize_t and ptrdiff_t, both signed. But according to theirs description it seems that they can both be of different bit size than size_t. But I need exactly same bit size as size_t but signed.

Comment: *But I need exactly same bit size as size_t but signed.* Use a `static_assert` for that: `static_assert(sizeof(std::size_t) == sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t), "error  message");`.  That's the best I know of.

Comment: @NathanOliver So usually `ptrdiff_t` can be used as signed `size_t`, but you have to check to be sure?

Comment: Also [`std::streamsize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize) "*used as a signed counterpart of `std::size_t`, similar to the POSIX type `ssize_t`*".

Comment: From my experience, the two types have the same size.  It's not guaranteed, but with the static assert you basically guarantee it.

Comment: `ssize_t` isn't standard C++; it's POSIX. But really, if you need a signed version of `size_t`, then your way seems fine. I would guess there isn't a standard one because negative "sizes" don't really exist, so the standard prefers more meaningful names like `ptrdiff_t` when it needs stuff like that.

Comment: There's [`std::ssize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), but it may be larger than `size_t`.

Comment: @user975989 I think you linked to the wrong one, that's the function page. In any case it may be worth keeping both types around. If you do get a bigger `ssize` then there will also be a corresponding `std::make_unsigned` of that. Oh on that note, does anyone know for sure if "the signed integral type corresponding to T" per `std::make_signed` is guaranteed identical in size, or if there's other logic involved? The page for `std::make_unsigned` is specific but only about enumerations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one place where the "signed version of `std::size_t`" (and also the unsigned version of `std::ptrdiff_t`) comes up in the standard: The `printf` format specifier `%zu` is for `std::size_t` objects. `%zd` is for objects of, as the C standard which the C++ standard refers to says, "the corresponding signed integer type [of `std::size_t`]"

```cpp
std::printf("%zu %zd %td %tu",
    std::size_t{0}, std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>{0},
    std::ptrdiff_t{0}, std::make_unsigned_t<std::ptrdiff_t>{0}
);
```

And since there is no type specifically named for `%zd` and `%tu`, I'm inclined to believe there is no standard name like you want (other than as `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>`).

---

As an aside, there is not much reason to want a signed variant of `std::size_t`: `std::size_t` is for the size of an object, and an object's size isn't signed.

`ssize_t` is only guaranteed to hold either `-1` or a non-negative value. It's guaranteed range is `[-1, SSIZE_MAX]` (And is a POSIX-specific type, not a standard C++ type). This is because it's used for "an unsigned value or -1 on error".

The C++ standard library just uses `std::size_t` for this, with `std::size_t(-1) == SIZE_MAX` instead to indicate the error/special value (See: `std::basic_string<...>::npos`, `std::dynamic_extent`), so you can just use `std::size_t` instead of `ssize_t` if you wanted an error value (or maybe `std::optional<std::size_t>`)

---

If you instead wanted "something to represent a size but is signed", `std::ssize(c)` ("signed `size`") returns `std::common_type_t<std::ptrdiff_t, std::make_signed_t<decltype(c.size())>>`. For array types, `std::ssize` returns `std::ptrdiff_t`. So probably use `std::ptrdiff_t` for this purpose.

---

If you wanted "the type used to represent the distance between two iterators" (including pointers), `std::ptrdiff_t` was made for this. This mostly coincides with the concept of signed sizes, and `std::iterator_traits<...>::difference_type` is usually `std::ptrdiff_t`.

---

These does not mean that `sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t) == sizeof(std::size_t)`. The standard does not define any relationship between them. Both of `sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t) < sizeof(std::size_t)` and `sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t) > sizeof(std::size_t)` seem theoretically possible, but I have not found any systems where this is the case. So a simple assertion should work on all platforms and allow you to just use `std::ptrdiff_t`:

```cpp
static_assert(
    sizeof(std::size_t) == sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t) &&
    static_cast<std::size_t>(std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max()) == std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / 2u,
    "ptrdiff_t and size_t are not compatible"
);
```

(There are many systems where `std::size_t` is `unsigned int` and `std::ptrdiff_t` is `signed long` but `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, so we have to check the ranges of the types rather than `std::is_same_v<std::ptrdiff_t, std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>>`)

Or just use `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>` like you already have.